# In Donjon's dynamic magic item creation process, what does "Meet all the item's prerequisites" mean?

Tags: dnd-5e, pathfinder-1e, crafting, conversion, unchained

While looking at [Donjon.bin.sh's dynamic magic item creation system for 5e](https://donjon.bin.sh/5e/item_creation/), converted from a similar [Pathfinder system](http://legacy.aonprd.com/unchained/magic/dynamicMagicItemCreation.html), I got a bit confused about the "Complete the item" challenge. One of the challenge's tasks, is "Provide the Requirements", where you have to "Meet all the item's prerequisites". But what does this mean?

My current interpretation is that the requirements are the gold and level requirements to craft the item, so that the only time you fail to meet the requirements, and thus fail that task, is if you try to craft a high-level magic item at a low level or similar.

What do you think? Is my interpretation correct, or does it mean something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## It means you need to meet the construction requirements for the item.

In Pathfinder if we look at an item like [Boots of Speed](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/a-b/boots-of-speed/), we see the following information:

> CONSTRUCTION REQUIREMENTS
>
> Feats [Craft Wondrous Item](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/craft-wondrous-item-item-creation), [haste](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste); Cost 6,000 gp.

So the item consists of 3 prerequisites:

- The Craft Wondrous Item Feat.
- The ability to cast Haste.
- Having 6000gp for crafting the item.

Thus if you lack the feat or the ability to cast the spell, you do not meet all the item's prerequisites, and would fail that task.

Given that I am unaware of any construction requirements in 5e, you would need to consult your GM on if there are any for an item.